# Can the term singular integral refer to a function which isn't smooth but that does not 'blow up'?

Tags: real-analysis

A colleague of mine is using the term singular integral to refer to integrals of functions which aren't analytic in the domain of integration. For example

$\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{|x|}dx.$

As he uses the term this would be a singular integral since while $\sqrt{|x|}$ does not blow up, it's first derivative does (and of course the higher derivatives too). When I try to google singular integral, I only get results that seem explicit about the integrand blowing up. So what's the consensus, is the term singular integral used also to refer to functions whose derivative blows up while the function itself does not?

Comment: The blowing up principal value integral is what I think of. There's nothing singular about the integral of a smooth function, many of which are not analytic.

Comment: I never used that term and I have never seen it., and if the behavior of the derivative is leading here, then $\int_{0}^1 \sqrt{x}dx.$ would also fall in that category. The latter integral is a common exercise though